# SQLAlchemy get position when ordered by value?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table which stores some movie info and a score.

I want to be able to know what position a movie has after being ordered by that score (ie 'The Shining' has the 10th highest score) but it would obvisouly not necessarily be in the tenth place of the database or have the id 10.

Would it be possible to get something like this, either through a query or somehow keeping it as a value in the table?

Thank you!

The table looks like this:

```
class MoviePersonScores(db.Model):
    movie_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('movie.id'), primary_key=True)
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'), primary_key=True)
    score = db.Column(db.Integer)
    person = relationship("Person", back_populates="movies")
    movie = relationship("Movie", back_populates="people")
```

Comment: If you are looking for the rank of a particular movie then you could use something like `SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 AS rank FROM movies WHERE score > (SELECT score FROM movies WHERE title = 'The Shining')`

Comment: Great solution @GordThompson --> consider writing it out as an answer? _(Also, bonus if you can configure it within sqlalchemy...)_

Comment: Side note to @Cobble, it would be helpful if you share what code you've tried. This Q has the tag `sqlalchemy` --> are you working within a session? Do you have tables defined?

Comment: Database specific. You'll need a window (or "analytic" is what Oracle calls them) function, like `rank()` in PostgreSQL. @GordThompson `COUNT(*)` is not a windowed function by default. That query will probably be an error.

Comment: @jpmc26 - That query works for me in SQL Server, at least.

Comment: @GordThompson yes I figured out how to do it with SQL as well, it's a SQLAlchemy query that I need.

Comment: @YaakovBressler I added the table to my question, I have no idea how I would even start to get the 'rank' since I am fairly new to SQL and I'm thinking it would need to be some query object I don't know about, but I am currently getting all the score objects by doing `MoviePersonScores.query.filter_by(movie_id=movie_id).all()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query can be broken down into two distinct steps:

1. get the rank of each record in your table
2. get the rank for a specific record

Because `rank` is relative to the entire collection of your table, you'll have no choice but to calculate the rank for every record. However, the magic of `sqlalchemy` allows you to leverage the database to execute those calculations.

Second, your application doesn't need the rank of every object. So we'll chain the query to only provide the one we'd like.

**More `sqlalchemy` magic, we can chain these queries to execute in a single database transaction:**

```
from sqlalchemy import func

# Assuming you have a session established somewhere
# though `MoviePersonScores.query` may work just the same

query = session.query(
    MoviePersonScores, 
    func.rank()\
        .over(
            order_by=MoviePersonScores.score
        )\
        .label('rank')
    )

# now filter
query = query.filter_by(movie_id=movie_id)

# now execute:
my_movie = query.all()

# Or, just get the first value
my_movie = query.first()
```

Comment: Oh is func.rank() a default function with SQLAlchemy?

Comment: What do you mean? @Cobble

Comment: Does that count as me creating a new function, or is that doing something behind the scenes?

Comment: Ah. This is a function which is communication through `sqlalchemy` to your database where the function is executed. So very behind the scenes. Also, execution on your db will be blazing fast. @Cobble

Comment: All right will have to try this out, will update on my results! Thank you!

Comment: This worked wonders! I did however then realize that my question wasn't complete, see I want to be able to get the rank based on a person (let's say I want the Nr. 1 Leaonardo Dicaprio movie) so I somehow first need to filter by person, and then get the rank based of the rsults of that ordered by the score.

I'll mess around and try to figure this out, as you may notice I'm very new to SQLAlchemy, would appreciate your input on how I would do this. :)

Comment: Consider posting as a new Question @Cobble --> as is the nature of solving a difficult problem, solving it occurs in discrete stages. Here is step 1! _(If you do choose to post a new Q, share the link here so I can take a look at it.)_

Comment: Created a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65761279/sqlalchemy-only-fun-rank-rows-in-table-where-value-x)