# SQLAlchemy only func.rank() rows in table where value = x

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65704957/sqlalchemy-get-position-when-ordered-by-value), I managed to get the rank of a table based on its value in that table. I can now rank movies based on a given score *(using the following table and method)*:

```
class MoviePersonScores(db.Model):
     movie_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('movie.id'), primary_key=True)
     person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'), primary_key=True)
     score = db.Column(db.Integer)
     person = relationship("Person", back_populates="movies")
     movie = relationship("Movie", back_populates="people")
```

And answer provided by [@YaakovBressler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10521959/yaakov-bressler):

```
from sqlalchemy import func

query = session.query(
    MoviePersonScores, 
    func.rank()\
        .over(
            order_by=MoviePersonScores.score.desc()
        )\
        .label('rank')
)
# now filter
query = query.filter_by(movie_id=movie_id)
# now execute:
my_movie = query.all()
```

This works great for getting the rank of ALL rows against each other. ***But now I want to rank based on the people in them.*** So `person_id` might be a ID of a director, so now if I want the rank of all Quentin Tarantino movies I would first need to filter the database for all of his movies and then apply the ranks, so how would I go about using the above method on a already queried and filtered set of rows?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In the case of `Quentin Tarantino` --> do you want to the list of all his movies, ranked in order by their score? _("This movie" is Tarantino's most popular movie...?)_

Comment: Also, thanks for the mention! Glad I can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this new query will be similar to the previous one, except you'll include a `partition_by` argument which is similar to a `groupby` method, and a `filter_by` to specify your given `person_id`:

```py
query = session.query(
    MoviePersonScores, 
    func.rank()\
        .over(
            order_by=MoviePersonScores.score.desc(),
            partition_by=MoviePersonScores.person_id,
        )\
        .label('rank')
)

# If you want to filter for a specific person, filter your query
my_person_id = 1 # substitute this for the correct id
query = query.filter(MoviePersonScores.person_id == my_person_id)

# I'd suggest ordering by the person_id, so you get neat results when debugging
query = query.order_by(MoviePersonScores.person_id, 'rank')

# Convert to a subquery so you can apply more filters
all_movies = query.subquery()

# Now filter your subquery based on a specific movie
movie_id = 1 # some movie ID
query = session.query(all_movies).filter(all_movies.c.movie_id == movie_id)

# Get all results
result = query.all()
```

Comment: Awesome this works like a charm when getting all of them! However when I now try to `filter_by(movie_id = movie_id)` it always seems to believe that it's number 1? So how would I go about doing what you asked in the comments, wanting to know one specific movies rank? Thanks for all the help you are amazing!

Comment: Hm, perhaps `rank` isn't being casted as an actual field? When querying for a person's movies, are the ranks correct? @Cobble I'm thinking that they're behaving as an index instead of a field..

Comment: I'm thinking converting to a subquery will solve this for you @Cobble --> let me edit my answer and let's see how it performs.

Comment: Getting `AttributeError: 'Alias' object has no attribute 'filter_by'`, have tried searching for a while but don't understand the root of the problem... .filter doesn't work either

Comment: Consider using `filter` instead of `filter_by` @Cobble

Comment: Let's break down the issue you're facing. Step 1: If you query a person, do you get all movies ordered by their rank? Step 2: If you filter that query, are the ranks missing? If so, what's happening most likely is the session is dropping all the movies which aren't `movie_id` then ranking them. In order to first rank, then drop, a subquery is executed.

Comment: yeah I tried that too with the same Error, but that it has no attribute 'filter', feels like it's not understanding that I'm continuing the query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227454/discussion-between-yaakov-bressler-and-cobble).

Comment: When I did the previous query without the subquery, I was indeed able to get all the movies with their ranks in the right order, the problem I am facing now is that it's not letting me filter after the subquery. So when getting all the movies related to Tarantino it works perfectly, I am now trying to just get 'Pulp Fiction' you know, and also see what rank that has.

Comment: _**Phew!**_ For anyone reading these comments, @Cobble and I hashed things out in SO's `discussion chat` and figured out the working details. Problem solved!